# how to search particular data in file and replace the string next to it in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Hello I am trying to search particular string in file and want to replace that string with other string in batch file.

For example, I am having a.txt containing following data:

```
line 1: Name: abc
line 2: Some words then age: 24 something
line 3: country:xyz
```

Now i want to find with "age:" and want to replace to

```
line 2: Some words then age: 30 something
```

and save in same a.txt.

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will replace every instance of `age: (whatever)` in a text.inf with `age: 30`:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=: " %%x in (text.inf) do (
  if "%%x"=="age" (
    echo %%x: 30 >> outfile.tmp
  ) else (
    echo %%x: %%y >> outfile.tmp
  )
)
move /y outfile.tmp text.inf
```

OK, your new specs make this more difficult, but...

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set line=
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%x in (text.inf) do call :workit %%x
move /y outfile.tmp text.inf
endlocal
goto :eof

:workit
set line=
  :workitloop
  set line=!line! %1
  if "%1"=="age:" (
    set line=!line! 30
    shift
    shift
    goto :workitloop
  ) else if "%1"=="" (
    echo !line:~1!>> outfile.tmp
  ) else (
    shift
    goto :workitloop
  )
goto :eof
```

Comment: thanks for ans.. but little problem is occuring. Actually the file is Line 2: Some words then age= 30 something

Comment: Getting error while trying 2nd method "The System can not find file specified" :(

Comment: I updated my code to take your new specs. "tokens=1,2* delims=: " means that the output text is split into three variables, in this case %%x %%y and everything else goes into %%z. "delims=: " means that each the places where the variables split is 'delimited' by one or more of a colen and/or a space. So `This get's:split` becomes `This` `get's` and `split`. Also `This has even more and:more` becomes `This` `has` `even more and:more`. (P.S. the "tokens=1,2*" was a mistake, I meant "tokens=1*" because there were not supposed to be any 3rd variables.)

Comment: Remove any `echo off`'s you have in the code and tell me what file it can't find. Also, remember to put the colon before the label `workit`. `call workit %%x` will try to find a .exe .com or .bat file to run. `call :workit %%x` will jump to the internal label `:workit`, and treat it as an external batch file.

Comment: I am getting Echo is ON 5-6 times in the outout file. :(

Comment: not getting any error after removing echo off but the text.inf contains only Echo is ON 5 times.

Comment: That tells me that the variable `line` is not getting filled.  Did you put the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the top, and then use the `!` to access variables instead of the `%`?

Comment: Yes I put the setlocal enabledelayedexpansion at top. Copied same script mentioned ain above answer.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working for you. I got proper results using the following test data in `text.inf`: Line 1: `name: Johnson Jhosifat` Line 2: `stupid silly age: 24` Line 3: `Current location: Georga Sweet Georga`.

Comment: Its correct its working with ur input file as mentioned above but still its not copying the words after the age:24.